# Using mcode within a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, listings, matlab

I have a presentation that I would like to include some matlab code in. For that purpose I have included the [mcode package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package), that basically configures the listings package. 
My problem is that the environment mode does not work inside a frame.

When I run the code below as it is (or with article documentclass) everything is as expected.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame} % code breaks if I include theese
\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:3 
   disp('cool'); % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§
end 
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{frame} % code breaks if I include theese
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the begin/end frame lines I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \lst@next
! Emergency stop
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The same happens if I use `\frame{...}` instead of `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Adding the option `[fragile]` should help.

Comment: Please consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package instead of `m-code`.